# Express $\cos{(2\pi/7)}$ in irreducible radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my book, irreducible radicals are defined as zeros of *irreducible* polynomials $X^n-a\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

First I have a question about this. In the book, it says irreducible radicals are introduced to avoid the ambiguity of the notation $K\subset K(\sqrt[n]{a})$. For instance if we adjoin to $\mathbb{Q}$ a zero of $X^8-16$ we get the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ too. Here, how does the concept of irreducible radical avoid the ambiguity? What I mean is, $X^8-16$ is reducible, but $X^4-2$ and $X^4+2$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{-2}$ would be irreducible radicals, right? How does this solve the problem?

The exercise itself asks to express $\alpha=\cos{(2\pi/7)}$ in irreducible radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$. The only way I can think of is find a polynomial which has $\alpha$ as a root and then use the explicit formula for the roots (if the polynomial has degree $\leq 4$), but this method obviously may not work. I'm sure there must be some trick to do this more easily.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question. I think of it in the following way. Let's look at some extension of the form $\mathbf{Q} \subset \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[n]{\alpha})$ with $(\sqrt[n]{\alpha})^n = \alpha$ where $x^n- \alpha \in \mathbf{Q}[x]$ irreducible. Now, notice that for two different $n-$th roots of $\alpha$, let's say $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, you will have isomorphic extensions ( $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1) \cong \mathbf{Q}(\alpha_2)$), because they have the same minimal polynomial. In the case when $x^n-\alpha$ is reducible this will not be the case.

But I do get the confusion, because it doesn't really seem necessary to introduce both concepts (irreducible radicals and radicals), to omit the ambiguity writing $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$.

I refer you to https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/simpleradical.pdf for more information.

Edit: To answer your comment under R.P.'s answer. To show how $\zeta_7$ can be expressed using irreducible radicals, you could create a tower of irreducible radical extensions such that $\zeta_7$ is in your last extension. Sometimes, the extension $\mathbf{Q} \subset \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ is already an irreducible radical extension.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos 2\pi/7=\frac{\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}}{2}$ with $\zeta_7$ a primitive seventh root of unity, we may attack the question by seeking to express $\zeta_7$ in terms of radicals.

In order to do this, one may use Kummer theory. The field extension $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ is cyclic of degree $6$. Now if $\mathbb{Q}$ would contain a primitive *sixth* root of unity $\zeta_6$, then Kummer theory says that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ is a radical extension, but alas this is not the case.

However, the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6)$ (where $\zeta_6$ is a primitive sixth root of unity) is in fact a radical extension, since we have $\zeta_6 = -\zeta_3 = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$, implying $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Now we may hazard the guess that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\zeta_7)$ *is* in fact a radical extension. This is not difficult to prove, in fact it is implied by Kummer theory (and a little bit of Galois theory showing that the degree $d=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})]$ divides $6$).

Since the proofs of Kummer theory are constructive, you can even write down an explicit generator $\beta$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\zeta_7)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ with $\beta^d$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: Firstly, $\zeta_6=1/2+\sqrt{3}/2i$, and $-\zeta_3=1/2-\sqrt{3}/2i$, so I think $\zeta_6\neq-\zeta_3$. Also, I don't get what you need that for, since knowing $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is enough, right? On the other hand, why are you proving that $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6)$ is a radical extension in the first place?

Comment: @cut The idea is to create a tower of radical extensions to get to an extension which contains $\zeta_7$ (as Anton Odina also pointed out).